# Is C++ virtual definition inherited automatically?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Is C++ virtual definition recursive? Consider

```
class Foo
     {
     public:
          virtual void a()=0;
     };

class Bar:public Foo
     {
     public:
         void a()
             {
         //...
             }
     };
```

If I now inherit `Bar` and overload `a` again, is that `a` also polymorphic?

Recursive means that

> Given a class `A` that has a virtual member `a`, and a virtual member of  the `n`:th subclass of `A`, then `a` is also a virtual member of the `n+1`:th subclass, for all `n`.

That is, virtual functions follow Peanos induction axiom and is not terminated after one level.

Comment: I think, you have shown example of redefinition, it is not overloading

Comment: Not "overload", but "override".

Comment: Yes, ... override. In any case `virtual` keyword is needed

Comment: Plus one, like the "Peanos induction axiom". That's posh for a Friday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inherit from `Bar` you should have

```
class Bar:public Foo
     {
     public:
         virtual void a() override
             {
         //...
             }
     };
```

So you are saying two things about `a()` here:

1. The function is virtual so anything that derives from `Bar` will treat the function as virtual
2. You are overriding the function `a` from the base class `Foo`

As [@MikeSeymour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126875/2296458) and [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126940/2296458) mentioned, the `virtual` keyword in `Bar` is superfluous as the function will be treated as `virtual` since it was in the base class. However, I tend to be in the habit of using `virtual`/`override` as shown in my example so it is immediately clear how this function is to be used at first glance of the class without having to walk up the inheritance.

Comment: +1, though I think you should mention that the `override` keyword is C++11 specific and only used for generating error messages (not obligatory syntax).

Answer (score 4):

"Recursive" isn't the right word; but yes, a function that overrides a virtual function is itself virtual.

Answer (score 4):

Any function with the (i) same name, (ii) the same parameter types, and (iii) a *related* return type in a base and child class that's marked `virtual` in a base class will also be virtual in the child class.

So yes, `void bar::a()` is virtual too. In fact, there is no way of removing the `virtual`-ness in the child class function.

Your terms are imprecise. *Overloading* is concerned with having functions with the same name but different parameter types. *Recursion* is a control flow technique. *Overriding* is the re-implementation of a base class function in a child class.

Comment: Yes recursion is a control flow technique. But there is also the term recursive definition. This is a definition that defines an object in terms of a root case. You could speak of recursive file permissions for directories etc...

Answer (score 2):

In the normal case, an overridden virtual function is itself virtual. It doesn't matter whether the parent class function was virtual because you used the `virtual` keyword or because it's own parent was virtual.

One thing to be careful of is when you "hide" one function with another of the same name but different signature. That function is *not* virtual!

```
class Foo
     {
     public:
          virtual void a()=0;
     };

class Bar:public Foo
     {
     public:
         void a(); // virtual
     };

class Baz1 : public Bar
     {
     public:
         void a(); // also virtual
     };

class Baz2 : public Bar
     {
     public:
         void a(int); // not virtual!
     };
```